# Cartesian and Inclusion-exclusion cardinality

Tags: cardinals, inclusion-exclusion

> Let $X,Y$ be finite sets such $\lvert X\rvert \leqslant \lvert Y\rvert,\\
> \lvert X\cup Y\rvert = 16,\\
> \rvert X\cap Y\rvert = 10,\\
> \lvert X\times Y\rvert = 168$
>
> Find: $\lvert X\times X\rvert$

setting $\lvert X\rvert=n$ and $\rvert Y\rvert=m$, using the inclusion exclusion principle i get, $n+m=26$

Do I assume that since $\lvert X\times Y\rvert=168$ implies $nm=168$ implies that $m=168/n$ then solve for $n$?

Comment: Yes.$\,\,\,\!\!\!$

Comment: 168 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 7. I have n²= 144.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets (here they are, because their union is finite), then the cardinality of $X \times Y$ is the cardinality of $X$ times the cardinality of $Y$, or in mathematical terms , $|X \times Y| = |X||Y|$. This would give:$mn=168$
Further, since $|X|+|Y|=|X \cup Y| + |X \cap Y|$, it follows that $|X| + |Y|=16+10=26$ i.e. $m + n = 26$. Now, solve the system $mn=168,m+n=26$, by putting $m=168/n$, and get the equation $n^2-26n+168=0$. Now, use the quadratic formula that you know very well:
$$
n=\frac{-26 \pm \sqrt{26^2-4*168}}{2} = \frac{-26 \pm \sqrt{4}}{2} = 12/14, m =14/12
$$

and you will notice that $m=12,n=14$, since $m \leq n$.

Comment: +1 for $|X|+|Y| = |X\cup Y| + |X\cap Y|$. However, I think it was not necessary to post a complete answer. This formula would have been sufficient.

Comment: Thanks. I love posting complete answers, though. Leave no stone unturned, kind of, although I'd like it if I could leave the questioner with some food for thought.

Comment: In my opinion, posting complete answers is often not for the benefit of the questioner because they don't learn from it.

Comment: You are right. Therefore, from next time I will post only half the answer, so that the person can get a lead from it, and find his way to the final answer. Is that fine, or in general should I refrain from answering trivial questions such as the above?

Comment: No, I think that's fine. If there was a thumbs up smiley here, I would post it. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for that. Good (evening/night/morning/afternoon) to you.

Comment: Night. ;o) Same to you. :o)

Comment: this was very helpful thank you so much

Comment: Ah, same to you @ Friedrich Philipp, and it's morning for me. Very happy to post on this site, smiling faces can only make you smile more.